# Unreal Engine 4, Leap Motion, and Dynamic material instance

Tags: unreal-engine4, leap-motion

I've been digging into the UE4 leapmotion plugin and have been trying to display the leapmotion raw camera image onto a dynamic material instance on a cube in the world.

I've managed to get it to display the start frame but it doesn't update.

What I'm doing is every time RawImageReceived event goes off I update the Texture2D param of my material instance. It works on frame 1, but doesn't update appropriately on subsequent RawImageReceived.

Here are the relevant screenshots:

This is where I set up receiving input:
[image: Event Handling]

My constructor
[image: Constructor]

This works the first time, but not on subsequent calls.
[image: Update Texture Param]

This is what Im seeing, but only the first initialized frame.
[image: What happens]

Maybe someone has played around with UE4 / LeapMotion enough that has done this already.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this later on, I've figured out the issue.

As of 27/04/16 the LeapMotion plugin content is a little bugged. You need the go into your LeapAnimConnector blueprint and EnableImageSupport on the leap controller in there to allow for this.